# Why are job links not saved?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

These days I am searching for a new collaboration and I am using SO Jobs to do so. I like the feature very much, but when I open a job listing in a new browser tab and then the next listing in another tab, my first listing is not marked as viewed in the Job list. It would be very useful for me to see which listing did I open. As far as I remember, opened listings were displayed as already opened, with a slightly different color even after reload. Is there a reason to not show the already opened links?

[image: Listing]

If we take a look at the listing above, we see only Senior Software Developer as an opened link, but I opened several other links as well.

Sidenote, only slightly related to the question: It would be very useful for me to mark companies which are not interesting for me. For example, if I read the job listing of a company and realize during that that I will not really be interested to read other possible listings for that company, it would be extremely helpful to mark it.

As things are standing, I need to take manual notes for each company or listing at a separate file, which solves the problem, but this feature does not seem to be very difficult. Abstractly, a new table for viewed listings with a foreign key to the user table and another table for blacklist of companies, having a foreign key to the user table, along with some very simple changes on the UI (CSS classes for the listings which are either blacklisted companies or viewed listings) would do the trick. A life cycle of a month for such records would more-or-less suffice in my opinion.

Comment: Looks like we don't have a `:visited` pseudo class set up on links. I'll ping the designers about it. Re. marking companies as not interesting: if you hover over the job you can dismiss it using the little `x` beneath the timestamp. Or on the listing itself use the `...` and selecting dismiss from there.

Comment: To clarify; this is browser supported behaviour that marks links as visited. Coloring of those links is specified via a CSS class.

Comment: @DeanWard I did not observe that x. As far as I understand this feature marks the job to be uninteresting. Can someone similarly mark a company as uninteresting?

Comment: Companies can be marked as uninteresting if they have a company page on /jobs. From the company page hit the ... button and dismiss.